# how count in pyspark?

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, count

I have a huge list of title. I wanna count each title in whole data set. for example:

```
`title`

   A
   b
   A
   c
   c
   c
```

output:

```
 title fre
     A   2
     b   1
     c   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `groupBy` `title` and then `count`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
df.groupBy('title').agg(f.count('*').alias('count')).show()
+-----+-----+
|title|count|
+-----+-----+
|    A|    2|
|    c|    3|
|    b|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Or more concisely:

```
df.groupBy('title').count().show()

+-----+-----+
|title|count|
+-----+-----+
|    A|    2|
|    c|    3|
|    b|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: is it take a long? how about if I wanna see the most and least frequencies?

Comment: Since my data set is very huge (10 gig with millions rows) I am looking for the faster way

Comment: If you just want to explore and check, you can do `.orderBy('count')` and then `.head(n)` for least frequent and `.tail(n)` for the most frequent.

Comment: I don't know if you can do faster than this. You'll always need to go through the whole dataset since you need a count.

Answer (score 0):

hi you can do that

```
 import pandas as pd
 title=["A","b","A","c","c","c"]
 pd.Series(title).value_counts()
```

Comment: It is related to bigdata. pyspark not pandas

Comment: can we do that by reduce map? I think that one should be faster